# How to continously integrate (CI) an forever running critical Python application?

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have written a crypto-trading bot in Python which runs 24-7. I want to continuously integrate new features and bug fixes to this app through CI software Jenkins. But the problem is I can't just kill the app, checkout the latest revision and restart the app; because the bot might have active trades to be sold (currently in a trade) at any given time. Killing the app would make the bot loose track of its orders. I was thinking of dumping my active trade data in a database, kill the app, update it, restart it and load the trade data from database to restore the bot's awareness of the trades. But I am not sure if this is best way to do this. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a way of signalling to the app to make a graceful exit?

Comment: 1. You could also store all your apps state in an in-memory shared service like redis, will also allow you to run multiple instances of your bot.  

2. write logic to listen to SIGTERM for example, and then gracefully exit, by not starting any new trades..

Comment: If it is critical, you *should* have multiple instances so that one can step in if another goes down for *any* reason (expected or not).

Comment: @Urban48 My application as an Telegram bot interface. Thats how I query it about ongoing trades, system status and shut down bot. When I command it to shut down, it will schedule a shutdown event as soon as all active trades executed. But this Telegram interface is not useful for Jenkins. I have read up on Redis, thank you for proposing it, I can use it to load my trade data when the app is restarted. But my question now is how can propagate an external kill signal like `kill <process number>` to my app and handle that to gracefully exit? I was thinking of creating CLI interface for my app.

Comment: @Urban48 So my question is, since my app is a multithreaded one, is it posible to create a thread which has CLI which listens to external commands?

Comment: @Vino. hey, if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up.

1. To save state consider using [Redis](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)
2. Listen to system signals to trigger graceful shutdown like so:

   ```
   import signal
   ... 

   def handler_stop_signals(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Handle system signals
       only SIGTERM expected to trigger this"""

       Log.log(__name__).info('Gracefully shutting down')
       my_process.shutdown()


   if __name__ == 'main':   
       signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler_stop_signals)
   ```

   No need for different process,cli, api. Register a listener and this callback will kick in once the signal is issued.
   For more info go [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html)

Then when you want to deploy new version with jenkins, just do your service stop or kill , then deploy and start.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A small modification from your suggestion; I am not using Redis, instead, using SQLite. Serves my purpose well.